# Build a "grouping" animation like Apple's iPad mail app

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

How can I do this "grouping" animation like Apple mail or the Gmail iPad app?

Does this need to be hard coded, and completely done with the animation framework, or does Apple expose an API for this to be done. I checked the developer docs, and I don't see anything like this. But Gmail was able to exactly replicate Apple's animation, and that's why I am curious to know if it can be done in an easier way.

[image]

Comment: @benzado is being a bit snarky, but he's right.  Legolas, you have more than enough rep to know that this question is clearly inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @CarlNorum I just updated my question. 'Use Programming' is not really a good answer. My question is whether Apple provides this for free, or does it need to be hard coded.

Comment: Your update greatly improves the question.  Unfortunately, I don't have much help for you.  Hopefully someone will!

Comment: Look into using a collection view,  Check out the WWDC sessions on collection views, they are loaded with useful information and ideas

Comment: Not being blessed with an iPad, I'm unfamiliar with the animation: would you mind describing it in the question? That would make it a better search target for future interested parties, too. As an aside, Google's got a lot of smart, hardworking people, and the company seems to be keenly interested in showing Apple up on its own platform. I suspect they "just" figured out how to do it on their own.

Comment: No, there is no public API for that. It's Core Animation + Core Graphics.

Comment: If you inspect the Gmail app, it's not exactly the same behavior, ie. select many emails and deselect one that is not at the top of the stack. In the Apple's app, the papers above are curled up before the  remove animation; in the Google's app, they do not. This reinforces a bit the idea that it's a custom-made component.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys : @JoshCaswell, Flink and DanielMartin. I have it all together on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am 95% sure Apple does not have a UIStackOfPaperViewController or anything like that. You would have to code this up yourself.

Conceptually, it isn't too complicated: a background view with a texture, and each subview tilted at a random angle and a drop shadow beneath. You could do the drop shadow by drawing a gradient in a view around the "real" view. Core Animation's default behaviors would probably do the right thing, e.g. if you create the page view off screen and then set the final location, it will fly onto the stack pretty much how you would like it.

If you don't need support for releases earlier than iOS 6, there's probably good stuff in the Collection View Controller to make this easier.

Hopefully that's enough information to get you started, but your question is really broad. It's difficult to answer "How do I do X?" if you don't specify your starting point, or answer "How can I do this in an easier way?" if you don't specify what you think the hard way is first.

Comment: Thanks Benzado! Was hoping there was something easier like 'UIStackOfPaperView' :P Anyhow, I guess i will write my own implementation of the stacks :D Thanks!